# Compare NSURL scheme in Swift with a String

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiwebview, ios8, uiwebviewdelegate

I was wondering if this is possible to do in swift and what it would be the way of doing it?

I just want to be able to compare? the scheme of my url to whatever string I want.. This is how I have been doing it in objc.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
        if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual: @"http"] || [request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
            return NO;
        }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `==` in Swift instead of `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` in Objective-C

```
if (request.URL.scheme == "http" || request.URL.scheme == "https") {
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: This helped me because I realized that in Swift I can compare `NSURL`s using the operator `==`, while in Objective-C I had to compare them using the method  `-(BOOL)isEqual:`

Answer (score 1):

Really Swifty:

```
if let scheme = request.URL.scheme {
    switch scheme {
    case "http", "https":
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Essentially, safely pull the scheme from the URL (could be nil after all) and then switch on it (which you can do in Swift but not Objective-C) using compound case statements.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers will fail if the source URL doesn't have the scheme in lowercase (i.e., `hTTp://…`).

Also, the other 2 answers fail to unwrap the optionals (`request.URL?.scheme?`).

Here's another option:

```
if let lowercaseScheme = request.URL?.scheme?.lowercaseString {
    if lowercaseScheme.rangeOfString("http") != nil {
        println("It's a match!")
    }
}
```

Or, in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3):

```
if let lowercaseScheme = request.URL?.scheme?.lowercaseString where lowercaseScheme.rangeOfString("http") != nil {
    println("It's a match!")
}
```

Or, if you don't need to actually *know* the scheme inside the block:

```
if request.URL?.scheme?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("http") != nil {
    println("It's a match!")
}
```

This will match `http`, `https`, and `hTTpS`. It will also match `lolHTTProfl`. If that's not okay in your use case, use the above answer's approach (the `==` operator), but with optional unwrapping and `lowercaseString`.